# Angular 2 bloking my css/js/img ressources

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvmH8.png)I'm developing an angular 2 web site, when import a css file or js file in my `index.html` nothing is loaded and when I check network traffic I see that those resources are not found (404 not found). I am sure that the path is correct. even images of the project are not found.
I want to import my resources in the index and not the angular-Cli.Thx for helping

this is my index:

```
<html>

<head>




    <link href="./app/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="./app/css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="./app/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="./app/css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="./app/css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="./app/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- calendar css-->
    <link href="http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/download/v1.1.0/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">







    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Byblos</title>
    <base href="/">
    <script src="./app/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="./app/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="./app/js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="./app/js/startmin.js"></script>

    <link href="./app/css/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/organigramme/demo/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/organigramme/demo/js/primitives.min.js"></script>
    <link href="./app/organigramme/demo/css/primitives.latest.css?3706" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/organigramme/demo/js/jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />




    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">



</head>

<body>
    <app-root>
        <div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
    </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "byblos",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngui/auto-complete": "^0.13.2",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.5.1-2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

[network traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjig2.png)

Comment: If you get a 404, then either the files are not served by the server, or the path is not correct. You're running on port 4200, so I assume you're using the CLI. Here is how you're supposed to deploy static assets with the CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration. Did you follow these instructions? What is the structure of your project and the location of your files?

Comment: i added a picture: the structure of the project .the file is imported with a correct path and

Comment: The structure shows that you didn't follow the instructions of the documentation I linked to.

Comment: can you please explain more I'm still a beginner, I didn't understand exactly what I need to do

Comment: If you want these static files to be served by Angular CLI, they must be located under src/assets, or they must be declared in the "assets" array of the file .angular-cli.json, as explained by the page I linked to. Do what you prefer, then use `ng build` to understand if and where the CLI copies the files under dist (which represents the root directory of your webapp)